# How to move Google Charts colour settings from file to another

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

So I am working on a project where the code already exists.

On 2 files as below, I need to remove the colour settings from the first file to the second file somehow in the IF statement.

The reason is the first file will be populated/injected with info from the backend but in order to do so I have to remove from the datasets propeties (label, fillColor, strokeColor, pointColor, pointStrokeColor, pointHighlightFill and pointHighlightStroke) array in file 1 to file 2 so to seperate styles from actual data that will be injected

I have tried simply adding the datasets section to the second file but just doesn't show anything - can it be added to the     Chart.types.Line.extend object or the AJAX section somehow?

Many thanks in advance

File 1: (Will have data injected to it):

```
{  
  "labels":[  
     "1 Feb",      
     "8 Feb",      
     "15 Feb",      
     "22 Feb",      
     "29 Feb",      
     "7 Mar",      
     "14 Mar",      
     "21 Mar",      
     "28 Mar",      
     "4 Apr",      
     "11 Apr",      
     "18 Apr",      
     "25 Apr"
  ],
  "datasets":[  
     {  
        "label":"Tenders",
        "fillColor":"rgba(253,0,20,0.2)",
        "strokeColor":"rgba(253,0,20,1)",
        "pointColor":"#fff",
        "pointStrokeColor":"rgba(253,0,20,1)",
        "pointHighlightFill":"#fff",
        "pointHighlightStroke":"rgba(253,0,20,1)",
        "data":[  
        77,
        55,
        40,
        65,
        59,
        80,
        81,
        56,
        55,
        65,
        59,
        80,
        75            
        ]
     }
  ]
}
```

File 2: (Where I want datasets properties to be):

```
if (document.getElementById("chart_div_won")) {

    Chart.types.Line.extend({
        name: "LineAlt",
        initialize: function(data) {
            Chart.types.Line.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
            var xLabels = this.scale.xLabels;
            var xLabelsLength = xLabels.length;
            xLabels.forEach(function(label, i) {
                if (i % 4 != 0 || i <= 1 || i == xLabelsLength - 1)
                    xLabels[i] = '';
            })
        }
    });

    var form_data = {};
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../../../sample_data/chart1.json",
        data: form_data,
        success: function(response) {
            var ctx = document.getElementById("chart_div_won").getContext("2d");
            var options = {
                responsive: true,
                maintainAspectRatio: true,
                pointDotRadius: 5,
                showXLabels: 5,
            };
            var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).LineAlt(response, options);

        },
        error: function() {
            $('div#chart-container').html('<div class="notification-body"><p class="notification-heading">Loading error...</p><p class="notification-description">Unfortunatley for some reason visual data failed to load.</p></div>'); 
        },
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    });
}
```

Comment: I think I some how have to define the style sets in the second file and then push them to the datasets array in the first file  - so looking into arrays and pushing into them, if anyone in the meantime can offer any help that will be awesome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I this is as far as I have got:

```
if (document.getElementById("chart_div_won")) {


    Chart.types.Line.extend({
        name: "LineAlt",
        initialize: function(data) {
            Chart.types.Line.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
            var xLabels = this.scale.xLabels;
            var xLabelsLength = xLabels.length;
            xLabels.forEach(function(label, i) {
                if (i % 4 != 0 || i <= 1 || i == xLabelsLength - 1)
                    xLabels[i] = '';
            })
        }
    });

    var datasets = [{
                        "label":"Tenders",
                         "fillColor":"rgba(253,0,20,0.2)",
                         "strokeColor":"rgba(253,0,20,1)",
                         "pointColor":"#fff",
                         "pointStrokeColor":"rgba(253,0,20,1)",
                         "pointHighlightFill":"#fff",
                         "pointHighlightStroke":"rgba(253,0,20,1)"}
        ];
    var form_data = {};

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../../../sample_data/chart1.json",
        data: form_data.push(datasets),

        success: function(response) {
            var ctx = document.getElementById("chart_div_won").getContext("2d");
            var options = {
                responsive: true,
                maintainAspectRatio: true,
                pointDotRadius: 5,                                                  
                showXLabels: 5,
            };
            var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).LineAlt(response, options);

        },
        error: function() {
            $('div#chart-container').html('<div class="notification-body"><p class="notification-heading">Loading error...</p><p class="notification-description">Unfortunatley for some reason visual data failed to load.</p></div>'); 
        },
        data: form_data.push(datasets),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    });
}
```

I am trying to add an array of datasets, then add that to the array in the first file, in the datasets array. No luck but I think my code in syntactically wrong in this answer above

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with this or a similar problem. It was easy in the end. All I had to do was add each property on at the end of the array.

Code

```
myLineChart.datasets[0].fillColor = "rgba(253,0,20,0.2)";
```

And so on